# jQuery animation is affecting position of siblings

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a group of elements that needs to be fixed to the right hand side of the window. Upon hovering on one element, I'd like that element to expand in width, but keep all it's siblings fixed to the side of the screen, while maintaining their current width.

Currently, upon hovering, the width of the selected element changes as expected, but also causes it's siblings to shift and no longer be fixed to the right hand side of the window (if i have the elements fixed to the left hand side of the window, the current code works perfectly, however i need it to be on the right).

Current Script:

```
$('.widget-item').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).animate({
        width: '75px', 
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '50px'
    }, 300);
```

});

Is there something I can add to the css / jquery to achieve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobbydigi/xpvt214o/907841/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margins are your friends here

try to add these 2 lines at your widget-item class

> margin-left:auto;
>
> margin-right:0;

```
.widget-item {
    background-color: rgb(130, 150, 165); 
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:0;
}
```